# magento 2.4 observer on product image change

Tags: event-observer, magento2.4, product-images

I have a grouped with some associated products. When the image on the grouped is updated, I'd like to save the same image on the associated products also.

I tried with the "catalog_product_gallery_upload_image_after" observer: this observer gets trigged on image change but it doesn't give me any info on the product that has been saved.

I also tried with the more generic "product_save" event (after and before): here I have the product data but I cannot fetch the image change.

Is there a way to trigger my code on the image change in a way that I can intercept the image change with the data of the product that has been saved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on this event - `catalog_product_save_commit_after`.

It will give updated image data as well.

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_commit_after">
        <observer name="some_random_event_name" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Observer\ImageTransfer"/> 
</event>
```

Sample code for `Vendor\Module\Model\Observer\ImageTransfer.php`

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $catalogProduct = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if (!$catalogProduct instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
            return;
        }

        $image = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getImage();
        $thumbnail = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getThumbnail();
        $small_image = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getSmallImage();

        if (($image != "no_selection") && (!empty($image))) {
            //do with $image
        }
        if (($thumbnail != "no_selection") && (!empty($thumbnail))) {
            //do with $thumbnail
        }
        if (($small_image != "no_selection") && (!empty($small_image))) {
            //do with $small_image
        }
    }
```